How do i allow clear items only on specific items on Select 2 multi select
Lets say I have item1,item2,item3 pre selected, how do i allow the user to delete only item3 and hide the X delete button from the others.
Thanks in advance

You can use data- attributes or classes to cause layout and behavior changes. Please post a minimal reproducible example if you want more help. What I see in the docs is adding items programmatically - the Option object is just an HTMLOptionElement so you can experiment with that, adding attributes, classes etc..

Hey @PeterPointer thanks for  your response, I'm sorry couldn't think of any solution to put on my question.
and for the Option object, I think I can use It just to add new options, I already know how to do that, but the problem is that how do I allow the user to delete only  specific one on that selected options.

It's difficult to answer without code. You can simply add your own data- attributes / classes and write a javascript / jquery click handler for removing the option. If you can't find it in select2's documentation you'll have to implement it yourself.

@PeterPointer U right i had to implement it my self since select2 isn't handling it by default, even tho I'm not satisfied with the implementation.
I posted the answer if u are interested

Not the best approach because I should not rely on the option label since it may not be unique but this is the only solution I got.
Let's say I have a select like this
<select name="" id="" multiple>
        <option selected value="1">item 1</option>
        <option selected value="2">item 2</option>
        <option value="3">item 3</option>
        <option value="4">item 4</option>
      </select>

and you want the selected values to be unclearable, u can achieve this with this simple code:
import "./style.css";
import $ from "jquery";
import select2 from "select2";
import "select2/dist/css/select2.min.css";
select2($);
// list of excluded items labels
const excludedItemsTitles = ["item 1", "item 2"];
//disable selected items function
const disbaleSelectedItems = function () {
  $(".select2-selection__choice").each(function () {
    //get the list item title
    const currentItemTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    //check if current item title on the array
    if (excludedItemsTitles.includes(currentItemTitle)) //remove delete button
      $(this).children("button.select2-selection__choice__remove").remove();
  });
};
$(() => {
  $("select").select2();
//calling it here so it disables the options u want on the initial load
  disbaleSelectedItems();
/* 
  this is required because select2 reRender everytime a change occur
  so u have to disable options again
*/ 
  $("select").on("change", disbaleSelectedItems);
});


u can also use the data-unclearable attribute for example on the options u want do not want them to be clearable, and check if the attribute is there.

You can have a property(say canDelete - which should be populated before you render the items in UI) for the items which will identify if a particular item can be deleted or not and based on the flag you can show or hide the "X" button.
Also if you can share the code which you have tried, it would be easier to understand your question.

Adding property wont work because select2 makes another elements that renders your options instead of the select options u provided, and the problem is how do I hide the X button? how do I know wish X button is for my element i want to hide?
I implemented a simple script if u want to check it out on the answers tab if u still want to see my code.
